# How to configure ipv6 static route for cisco router

Tags: routing, ipv6, static

I've tried but i don't know if i got it right. So per the picture, If i want to set a static route from R1 to SW1 subnet The command should be ipv6 route 2001:d79:1:345::/64 2001:d79:1:13::

[image]

Comment: The destination of a route should be an address, not a subnet (or in general, an interface.) You want the route pointed to the *address* of f0/1 on R3, not the ::/64 subnet between them. Of course, for everything to work, there has to be a return path (routes) as well. Getting *TO* the network is only half the problem.